# how to get the first tweet from my twitter and display it on my webpage?

Tags: asp.net

Please can somebody help to get the first tweet from my twitter and display it on my website.
I am using asp.net 2.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this depending on your requirements. Personally, I have accomplished this using the [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) library.

```
var feed = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(new UserTimelineOptions() {
                            CacheOutput = true,
                            CacheTimespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                            ScreenName = "twitter_username",
                            Count = 1
                        });
var firstPost = feed.FirstOrDefault();
```

The advantage of this approach is that you are not required to have a Twitter API key in order to pull the data. It doesn't get much simpler than this!

### Update

After you clarified .NET 2.0 I found this .NET 2.0 Twitter API wrapper. Haven't used it myself, but it may be worth a look. [Yedda Twitter C# Library](http://devblog.yedda.com/index.php/twitter-c-library/)

If that that library/wrapper won't do, [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) also has a .NET 2.0 compatible binary.

Just a caveat, JSON.NET would be the most involved simply because the various wrappers that exist will be specialized to Twitter, whereas JSON.NET is just a general JSON parser (Twitterizer even uses it).

In my own opinion, possibly the easiest solution of all is to use jQuery to pull up the API for you. Obviously, that would be done as a client event so it would not be as "ideal" as the alternative. Still it's a the most "no-fuss" solution. Here's a blog post on [calling the Twitter API with jQuery](http://bagofspanners.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/calling-the-twitter-api-with-jquery/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, But this twitterizer needs framework 3.5 or later, but in my project I am using 2.0 framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) (works on .NET 2.0)

This example doesn't show your tweet, but you get the idea of how easy it is.

```
using TweetSharp;

TwitterService service = new TwitterService();
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = service.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();
foreach (var tweet in tweets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
}
```